# How can I ssh to google colaboratory VM?

Tags: ssh, google-colaboratory

How can I ssh to google collaboratory VM? Is there a more straightforward way to do it than to create ssh tunnel from jupyter notebook to a remote server?

Answer (score 25):

Here's another solution - essentially, the same as presented by @tamlyn, but much shorter. There's a [colab-ssh](https://pypi.org/project/colab-ssh/) connector, which automates the process. All you have to do is register a free account on [ngrok](https://ngrok.com). Then, you need to copy your [auth token](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth/your-authtoken). Now, in the destination Colab notebook:

```
# Install colab_ssh
!pip install colab_ssh --upgrade

from colab_ssh import launch_ssh
launch_ssh('YOUR_NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN', 'SOME_PASSWORD')
```

You should get the connection parameters (pay attention to the port). 
Now you can connect to the Colab VM by using the provided details, for example: `ssh -p 15892 root@0.tcp.ngrok.io`, where `15892` is the random port number you need to change. Naturally, you will be prompted for the previously set password.

This is obviously limited by free ngrok account restrictions, but it should be enough for small tasks.

If you get `IndexError: list index out of range`, don't worry. From my experience, it will still work - you can get the port and address from [ngrok active tunnels list](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/status/tunnels).

Comment: This works, thank you. The longer code in the other answer for some reason didn't.

Comment: Is it valid for today? Receiving `IndexError: list index out of range` on the `launch_ssh`.
UPD
`! curl http://localhost:/api/tunnels` fails to connect, connection refused. Is it possible Google restricted connection or any other port available?

Comment: @A.Ametov yes, please check the last paragraph of my answer - it works despite of this error, at least for me. You just have to check the IP on the ngrok panel.

Comment: Thanks! Just restarted the runtime and got the port

Comment: Works nicely! Thank you!

Comment: It Doesn't Connect, "Connection Timed out", What Should I Do Now? Is this still working?

Answer (score 23):

Try pasting the following into a cell and running it (inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/creotiv/d091515703672ec0bf1a6271336806f0)):

```
import random, string, urllib.request, json, getpass

#Generate root password
password = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(20))

#Download ngrok
! wget -q -c -nc https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
! unzip -qq -n ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

#Setup sshd
! apt-get install -qq -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0 openssh-server pwgen > /dev/null

#Set root password
! echo root:$password | chpasswd
! mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
! echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
! echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
! echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64-nvidia" >> /root/.bashrc
! echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /root/.bashrc

#Run sshd
get_ipython().system_raw('/usr/sbin/sshd -D &')

#Ask token
print("Copy authtoken from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth")
authtoken = getpass.getpass()

#Create tunnel
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok authtoken $authtoken && ./ngrok tcp 22 &')

#Get public address and print connect command
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels') as response:
  data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
  (host, port) = data['tunnels'][0]['public_url'][6:].split(':')
  print(f'SSH command: ssh -p{port} root@{host}')

#Print root password
print(f'Root password: {password}')
```

[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is used to create a tunnel to the machine and give it a publicly accessible hostname. You will need to sign up, copy your auth token and provide it to the Colab notebook when prompted.

When it completes, it will print out your connection details, something like:

```
SSH command: ssh -p12312 root@0.tcp.ngrok.io
Root password: abcdeLMh6vpNViGHQbXi
```

If this last step fails, try running the cell again or create a new cell with just the following and read the JSON output to find the hostname and port.

```
! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels
```

Comment: I have got the password using this now but where is the username and IP to connect?

Comment: It appears that Google has perhaps disabled ssh access lately? The above code gives me the error `invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.`

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I've just posted a new answer, which might solve your problem - at least it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Since Google had decided to block `ngrok` for Google Colab, you might need to use different kind of tunel for SSH. Which you can try this:

```py
!pip3 install linus_colab_ssh

from colab_ssh import setup_ssh, loop_forever

public_key = '<YOUR_PUBLIC_SSH_KEY>'
setup_ssh(public_key)
loop_forever()
```

More details can be found in [here](https://github.com/lamhoangtung/colab_ssh). Good luck!

Comment: I couldn't find any proof of 'Google had decided to block ngrok'. The solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682149/4752223 works just fine as of 2022-02-10.

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/tmate-io/tmate/issues/218 :

```
!pkill -9 tmate
!wget -nc https://github.com/tmate-io/tmate/releases/download/2.4.0/tmate-2.4.0-static-linux-i386.tar.xz &> /dev/null
!tar --skip-old-files -xvf tmate-2.4.0-static-linux-i386.tar.xz &> /dev/null
!rm -f nohup.out; bash -ic 'nohup ./tmate-2.4.0-static-linux-i386/tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock new-session -d & disown -a' >/dev/null 2>&1
!./tmate-2.4.0-static-linux-i386/tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock wait tmate-ready
!./tmate-2.4.0-static-linux-i386/tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock display -p "Connect with SSH address: #{tmate_ssh}"
!./tmate-2.4.0-static-linux-i386/tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock display -p "Connect with web: #{tmate_web}"
```

It works as of 11/Sep/2021.

Answer (score 1):

[This jupyter notebook](https://gist.github.com/shadiakiki1986/4aa8f128d816f31203e05fb8fbc2fabf) illustrates how to use an ssh reverse tunnel to do this.

Compared to the previous answers, the ssh reverse tunnel method has the following differences:

- does not require ngrok on the colab VM
- requires ngrok on the local machine (from which you're ssh'ing) only if it doesn't already have a public IP
- requires sshd on the local machine

Answer (score 0):

From this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rava-dosa/ca2d3f2758d720d2684ec97cf684b6ba)

```py
import random, string, urllib.request, json, getpass

#Generate root password
password = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(20))

#Download ngrok
! wget -q -c -nc https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
! unzip -qq -n ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

#Ask token
print("Copy authtoken from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth")
authtoken = getpass.getpass()

#Create tunnel
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok authtoken $authtoken && ./ngrok tcp 22 &')
```

So now your ngrok tunnel has been established(hopefully). Now try to install ssh server. This is meant to fail, but still do it.

```py
#Setup sshd
! sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

As the above command failed, run this.

```py
# if install fail run this, uncomment and run the below line
! sudo apt-get install openssh-server --fix-missing
```

Now run this, this does basic changes in ssh config to make sure that you are able to remote login in colab.

```py
#Set root password
! echo root:$password | chpasswd
! mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
! echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
! echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
! echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64-nvidia" >> /root/.bashrc
! echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /root/.bashrc
```

Now we will try to run ssh-daemon

```py
get_ipython().system_raw('/usr/sbin/sshd -D &')
# to check if ssh is running on port 22 or not or installed or not
! sudo apt install net-tools
! netstat -plant | grep ssh
! which sshd
```

Last two commands should give output as

```
/usr/bin/sshd 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 1008/sshd
```

To get ssh configuration and credentials

```py
# get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok authtoken $authtoken && ./ngrok tcp 22 &')
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels') as response:
  data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
  (host, port) = data['tunnels'][0]['public_url'][6:].split(':')
  print(f'SSH command: ssh -p{port} root@{host}')
#Print root password
print(f'SSH password: {password}')
```

if due to some reason the above command, fails, run that again, until it works

Answer (score -6):

You can execute shell commands in a notebook using `!`, for example:

```
!echo "Echo in shell"
```

There's presently no support for directly connecting to the backend via SSH.