# Sending file to host with Colab

Tags: scp, google-colaboratory

I want to share a Colab file using scp
I created a RSA keypair using SSH-keygen. When I run:

```
!scp "/full/path/to/file"  [user]@[host]:~/path/to/dest
```

I get (without password prompt):

```
>>>Host key verification failed.
>>>lost connection
```

Classical answers as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147698/host-key-verification-failed-error-when-transfering-files-using-scp-command) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379495/host-key-verification-failed-when-i-use-scp) do not work in this context because the colab environment gives no access to the relevant files:

```
!ssh-keygen -R [host]
>>>do_known_hosts: hostkeys_foreach failed: No such file or directory

!rm /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts
>>>rm: cannot remove '/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts': No such file or directory

!scp "/full/path/to/file" -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' [user]@[host]:~/path/to/dest
```

same

paramiko pip module:noodles forever, no result whatsoever

Comment: I am not bound to using scp

Answer (score 1):

you need first to make an ssh connection to your colab account by a terminal that could connect by ngrok which code is in the following

```
import random, string, urllib.request, json, getpass

#Generate root password
password = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(20))

#Download ngrok
! wget -q -c -nc https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
! unzip -qq -n ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

#Setup sshd
! apt-get install -qq -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0 openssh-server pwgen > /dev/null

#Set root password
! echo root:$password | chpasswd
! mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
! echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
! echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
! echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64-nvidia" >> /root/.bashrc
! echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /root/.bashrc

#Run sshd
get_ipython().system_raw('/usr/sbin/sshd -D &')

#Ask token
print("Copy authtoken from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth")
authtoken = getpass.getpass()

#Create tunnel
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok authtoken $authtoken && ./ngrok tcp 22 &')

#Get public address and print connect command
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels') as response:
  data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
  (host, port) = data['tunnels'][0]['public_url'][6:].split(':')
  print(f'SSH command: ssh -p{port} root@{host}')

#Print root password
print(f'Root password: {password}')
```

after connecting to colab by The terminal you are allowed to use SCP on that

Comment: I found another way for connecting to colab by terminal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435880/12925941)