# google colab ssh connection timesout

Tags: ssh, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I am trying to follow the numerous tutorials and gists such as:

`https://gist.github.com/creotiv/d091515703672ec0bf1a6271336806f0`
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459804/how-can-i-ssh-to-google-colaboratory-vm/53252985#53252985`

When I run the steps, it seems like everything went fine (I get the root password), but I do see this:

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
```

but unfortunately, after all the steps when I do the following on my local machine:

```
ssh -p17057 root@0.tcp.ngrok.io
```

I get:

```
ssh: connect to host 0.tcp.ngrok.io port 17057: Connection timed out
```

I am on vanilla Debian Buster - any pointers to why this is happening would be incredibly useful to debug

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble ssh'ing into the ngrok tcp tunnel. I was using my local laptop as the access point to the colab VM. What I did was fire up an EC2 instance on AWS and use that instead. Also, I used ssh reverse tunnel and dropped the need for ngrok altogether since the ec2 machine already had a public IP. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63186681/4126114