# root@0.tcp.ngrok.io: Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: linux, ssh, google-colaboratory, ngrok

Reference: https://medium.com/@meet-minimalist/how-to-ssh-into-google-colab-and-run-scripts-from-terminal-instead-of-jupyter-notebook-3931f2674258

I had tried to SSH into Google Colab, after I generated password, I type this command into my terminal (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
ssh root@0.tcp.ngrok.io -p <my_port>
```

And it required password, I tried to use the password which was generated before that by my permission had been denied.

Answer (score 1):

If the solution in "[How can I ssh to google colaboratory VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252985/6309)" does not work, you can try and follow instead "[Colab-SSH-and-GDrive](https://github.com/vdivakar/Colab-SSH-and-GDrive)" from Divakar Verma.

> 1. Create your free account at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and get the authtoken.
>    This will be used in Step4.
>    Should look like `$ ./ngrok authtoken ZT64bWYnXsdTAdfdassJej42auAQqKqZHn2Sh4g2sfAD`
> 2. Get the public key of your local machine.
>
>    ```
>    $ ssh-keygen
>    $ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
>    ```
> 3. Go to your colab notebook.
>    Copy the content from template provided above (`ssh_colab.ipynb`).
> 4. Execute the colab notebook. Mount your Google Drive. When prompted, enter the authtoken obtained in Step1. Lastly, it will ask the public key of your local machine obtained in Step2.
> 5. Now you should get output something like `ssh root@0.tcp.ngrok.io -p 12**6`.
>    The port will be different for your case. Go to your local machine and run this ssh command. Done!