# How to connect VScode to colab / paperspace / etc

Tags: visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, google-colaboratory

Cloud instances like google colab, paperspace gradient etc. offer free or very inexpensive  options at ~10$/months for storage, GPU compute, ready-to-use containers and a jupyter notebook/lab IDE. It's great for hobby prototypes.

However, personally, I much prefer IDEs like VSCode for developing even small projects. Given that VSCode offers ssh-remote access to machines and even docker containers, what are the best options to realize this? Already tried [colab-ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459804/how-can-i-ssh-to-google-colaboratory-vm) which works but feels a bit sluggish. Maybe there are better options?

On the other side, one can rent instances like AWS p2.xlarge, but with costs of 1$/h they become significantly more expensive than the above options (sidenote: Why is there such a discrepancy?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SSH onto notebook server

Most managed notebook services don't allow/support SSH.

- Colab states this in its [terms of service](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html).
- Paperspace also seems to not support it (according to this [forum thread from 2018](https://forums.fast.ai/t/how-to-ssh-into-paperspace-gradient-instance/17216/3)).
- It may be possible with Sagemaker if you [set up a bastion host](https://ruslanmv.com/blog/How-to-connect-to-Sagemaker-Notebook-via-SSH).

### VS Code server

[VS Code server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) you lets you run VS Code on the notebook server, and connect through a local VS Code without SSH.

- in Colab: [colabcode](https://github.com/abhishekkrthakur/colabcode)
- in Paperspace: [gradient-coder](https://github.com/Paperspace/gradient-coder)

On the client side you can connect via the [Remote - Tunnels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels) extension.