# How to access the locally hosted elasticsearch server on google collab

Tags: python, elasticsearch, networking, server, google-colaboratory

Currently we are working on local elastic search server to store and perform the operartions. so i have installed and working elasticsearch instance on my local machine .but i want to access this server from the google collab so when i try to access it using the " !curl **http://localhost:9200/** " It saying connection refused and when i the use IP address i.e **http://[My IP Address:9200] /** it says connection timed out .
in elasticsearch.yml i have removed authentication and setted **network.host : 0.0.0.0**
the server is up and running on local host but not accesible from the google collab what should i do ?

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google colab is running in VM on a remote server in Google's GCP. I can only assume that your machine is running on your local network. Therefore your notebook simply cannot get access to your instance. There are several ways to solve this issue:

1. If you are working from home, you can forward a port from on your router to your local machine running elasticsearch. This solution depends on the model of the router/firewall that you are using and I wouldn't recommend exposing unprotected instance of elasticsearch to outside world.
2. A much safer way would be to create an ssh tunnel from your machine to colab instance. This is covered in details in [How can I ssh to google colaboratory VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459804/how-can-i-ssh-to-google-colaboratory-vm)
3. Instead of running elasticsearch locally you can run it in one of the available services. For example https://www.elastic.co/cloud/ there is a free trial and you get proper security setup and it is already accessible form the internet.

I hope that helps.